# Avoiding duplication when joining on a column with duplicate values

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to join on a table column that has multiple duplicate results in the column I'm trying to join on. An example looks kinda like:

```
Month  | code | crime  
-----------------------
2017-1 | EO99 | Burglary
2017-1 | EO99 | Shoplifting
2017-2 | FO01 | Anti-Social Behaviour
```

The table that's being joined looks like:

```
Contents | F4  
-----------------------
EO99     | 4581  
EO98     | 10255 
FO01     | 4898
```

And the desired result is:

```
Month  | code | crime                  | Population
---------------------------------------|------------
2017-1 | EO99 | Burglary               | 4581
2017-1 | EO99 | Shoplifting            | 4581
2017-2 | FO01 | Anti-Social Behaviour  | 4898
```

I'm trying to join on that code column  to add a fourth column that has population data. Here's my current query:

```
DROP TABLE LSOA_crimes_2017_joined;
SELECT DISTINCT
    crimes_data_GM_2017_2018.*, 
    ['2017_LSOA_Pop.'].F4 AS Population
INTO 
    LSOA_crimes_2017_joined
FROM 
    crimes_data_GM_2017_2018 AS data,
    ['2017_LSOA_Pop.']
INNER JOIN 
    crimes_data_GM_2017_2018 ON
    crimes_data_GM_2017_2018.[LSOA code] = 
    ['2017_LSOA_Pop.'].[Contents]
WHERE 
    crimes_data_GM_2017_2018.Month LIKE '2017%';
```

Using Distinct helped to avoid the crazy duplicates it was making for every result, but because some of the results are exactly the same yet different instances of crime, I need both to be in the new table.

Comment: Sample data from only one table is not particularly helpful.  Sample data from all tables, along with desired results, and a clear explanation of the results you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've edited to add some

Comment: `DISTINCT` is usually a code smell that the joins haven't been thought through properly. You really need to explain what duplicates you have and how you want to deal with them. And you really should choose better names for your tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had both tables in the from clause and that was creating the cartesian product. You may need to do something like this:

```
DROP TABLE LSOA_crimes_2017_joined;
SELECT DISTINCT
    crimes_data_GM_2017_2018.*, 
    ['2017_LSOA_Pop.'].F4 AS Population
INTO 
    LSOA_crimes_2017_joined
FROM 
    crimes_data_GM_2017_2018 AS data
INNER JOIN 
    ['2017_LSOA_Pop.'] ON
    crimes_data_GM_2017_2018.[LSOA code] = 
    ['2017_LSOA_Pop.'].[Contents]
WHERE 
    crimes_data_GM_2017_2018.Month LIKE '2017%';
```

Comment: I didn't have both initially. I put the second one in because I kept receiving the error "The multi-part identifier could not be bound" for crimes_data_GM_2017_2018.LSOA code and crimes_data_GM_2017_2018.Month.

 I also receive the error "The column prefix 'crimes_data_GM_2017_2018' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query." 
and the error "An object or column name is missing or empty". 

But I get none of these errors when I put in the second table in the from clause.

Comment: you just need one table in the from clause and the other in the inner join with the condition as shown above. Also, unless there are duplications in the table crimes_data_GM_2017_2018 you don't need the distinct

Comment: when you put both table in the FROM clause, that was that produced the "crazy duplications" as it combines each row of one table with each row of the other (Cartesian product)